# Actionbar button background

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar

I want to customize actionbar buttons with an image both for pressed and not pressed state. I put a drawable selector on android:icon with two states (pressed and not pressed). The problem is that, if I press the button, I still have the blue background (ics holo style) along with my pressed button icon. How can I remove this behaviour from actionbar customized icon buttons?

Thanks

Comment: Does the icon show pressed and not-pressed state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have fixed the problem putting

```
 <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@color/transparent</item>
```

in styles.xml. I thought it would have affected all the select styles but it seems it affects just the actionbar.

Comment: Where should I put this line exactly? I have tried to extend the @style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar and to place both lines of code in it. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

I think the more specific way is to put this attribute in your application Theme:

```
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Also put this if you're using ActionBarSherlock:

```
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```