# Remove blue glow from Android actionbar button press

Tags: android, button, colors, android-actionbar

I was trying to remove the blue color that shows whenever I click an item on the actionbar in Android. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923364/remove-actionbar-item-blue-background) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285068/actionbar-button-background), I tried adding these to my `styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@color/Silver</item>
```

and

```
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
```

The first one does not make any difference, where as the second one gives me a compile-time error saying that to use it the `minimum api level required is 14 whereas mine is 11`. I am not using ActionBarSherlock. 
 So is there any way to remove the blue color and use a custom color?

Comment: yup, use a custom style from here http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground" tools:targetApi="14">@drawable/my_background_actionbar_button</item>
```

Make sure to have the "tools" namespace in the top line of the xml file

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

If you are using the support library (appcompat), add this for older versions

```
<item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/my_background_actionbar_button</item>
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but it makes no difference. The background on button press is still blue. Not sure whats wrong.

Comment: Look at where you put these. In your styles.xml you should define a theme your app is using. It is typically called AppTheme. The customization option should go directly into the theme. In your manifest, make sure your activity uses the customized theme.